# ATxmega128A1 led blinking

Tags: c

I'm trying to program AVR Xmega-A1 xplained board and I have little problem.

My code:

```
unsigned char state = 1; // temporary variable for leds states

    while (1)
    {

        if ( state == 1)
        {
            leds = 0b00000001; // led0 is on

            if(~readSwitches() & 0b00000001)
            {
                state = 2;
            }
            if(~readSwitches() & 0b00000010)
            {
                state = 3;
            }
        }

        if ( state == 2)
        {

            leds = blink0(leds);


            if (~readSwitches() & 0b00001000)
            {
                state = 1;
            }

        }

        if ( state == 3)
        {
            leds = 0b00000000;
            if(~readSwitches() & 0b00000100)
            {
                state = 1;
            }

        }
        writeLeds( ~leds );

    }
```

It should do following:

**when turned on:** only led0 is on

**sw0:** led0 blinking

**sw1:** led0 off  // not working if blinking

**sw2:** led0 on   // not working if blinking

**sw3** : turns blinking off

Currently it almost works like should.. only problem is led0 is blinking when board is turned on. Any tips to change it?

Comment: why initial value for `state` is `1` instead of `0`? `leds` will stay to `0` (if that's value you initialize it) and all leds will be off. (note it may be also your state `3` if it's allowed in your _state machine_).

Comment: Well I have schema were state is 1, but it doens't really matter if it is 0 or 1 in current code.. if I change it to 0 all leds will be off like you said, but if I make any function or statement to change it to 1 for some reason it rushes for blinking function

Comment: Try to write down _states_ and _conditions_. State 1 is "led 0 on", state 2 is "blinking" and state 3 is all off. Is state 3 a valid initial condition? (valid = it is ok to move to state 1 switching on 3rd switch). If 3 is not valid initial state then you have to set state to 0 as initial value and add a new state transition check (if state==0...).

Comment: Thanks for time and tips.. managed to find solution.. I just simply changed state to 0 and added

if ( state == 0){ 
leds = 0b00000001;
if(~readSwitches() & 0b00000001) {state = 1; }}